# Создать ссылку на скачивание файла

Tags: c#, asp.net

У меня такой вопрос. Значит я добавил файл excel через resources. Потом я открываю через код добавляю некоторые данные.

```
string printoutFileName = @"C:\Users\print.xlsx";
byte[] templateBinaryContent=Properties.Resources.print;
Application excelApp = new Application();
Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(printoutFileName);
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
worksheet.Cells[1,1]="blabla";
workbook.Save();
```

И этот файл сохраняется в папке Документы.

А мне нужно чтобы когда нажимал кнопку (точнее в браузере линк "скачать"), файл скачивался в браузере.

Comment: "Нажимал кнопку" - где нажимал? Нужно в браузере кликать на линк "скачать эксель".

Comment: Да, на сайте должна находиться кнопка скачать

Comment: А зачем вам templateBinaryContent (неиспользуемая) если вы по факту всё равно берёте `var fileContent  = File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath );`? Т.е. у вас файл не embedded resources?

Comment: @AK создал templateBinaryContent а потом не смог использовать это когда создавал объект класса application :(

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере action возвращают [ActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx) и чаще всего это строки, но вообще ещё можно вернуть [json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) или даже целый файл.

Создайте в контроллере action возвращающий [FileContentResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public FileContentResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
    {
        byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPathToFile);
        var fileType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        var fileName = "test.xlsx";

        return this.File(content, fileType, fileName);
    }
}
```

См. также:

- [Отправка файлов в ASP.NET MVC](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/3.9.php)
- [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4212861/5752652)