# Вывод изображения в представлении ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, файлы, asp.net-mvc, view

В контроллере у меня есть два метода, Get и Post. В представлении первого создана форма, в которой пользователь загружает изображение и текстовый файл. В пост методе происходят некие операции над данными файлами, а потом возвращает обработанное изображение.  И мне нужно чтобы я вернул не просто изображение (как это сделано в моем коде ниже), а чтобы вернулось представление, то есть оформленная страница, где будет вставлено данное изображение. Подскажите, как я могу это сделать? И еще вопрос, как я могу реализовать возможность загрузки этого изображения на ПК при нажатии соответствующей кнопки в представлении. 
Ниже представлен код контроллера

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Encrypted()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Encrypted(HttpPostedFileBase upload1, HttpPostedFileBase upload2, string key)
{
    string fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(upload1.FileName);
    string fileName2 = Path.GetFileName(upload2.FileName);

    upload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName1));


    Image image = Image.FromStream(upload2.InputStream);
    image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName2));
    string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName2);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagePath);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + fileName1));
    string text = sr.ReadLine();
    text = Crypto.EncryptStringAES(text, key);

    var bmp1 = SteganoHelper.embedText(text, bmp);
    byte[] arr = bmp1.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Bmp);

    return  File(arr, "image/bmp");

}
```

Comment: Просто отправите пользователя на другую вьюху, где будет это изображение

Comment: @Jagailo, я не понимаю, как его отправить на другую вьюху в своем пост методе

Answer (score 1):

Есть варианта.

Первый: изображения достаточно маленькие и их можно передать через data:uri - в этом случае достаточно одного экшна/представления.

Второй: изображения крупные и сохраняются в базу, делаете два экшена/представления: в первом выводите станицу с тегом img который имеет в src ссылку на второй экшн.

Второй вопрос [посмотрите тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830433/213987)

Comment: Я не совсем понял по поводу второго. То есть результатом моего Post метода будет представление, в котором будет тег img с ссылкой на экшн, который отвечает за скачивание?  Я просто не понимаю, каким способом вывести мое изображение в пост методе , и чтобы рядом с ним была ссылка на скаичивание

Comment: @YuraMorozov Результатом вашего POST метода загрузки будет [редирект](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level4/4_5.php) на GET-метод показа загруженной картинки.